# Python Gsheets insert_row is skipping data

Tags: python, gspread

I have a double-nested dictionary, where the value returned is a list with characteristics about a person. I want to write each value in the list to google sheets, so have used gspread. Here's my code:

```
for person in list_id: 
    index = 2

    for key, value in enrich_dict.items():

        for keytwo, valuetwo in value.items():
            row = [valuetwo[0], valuetwo[1], valuetwo[2], valuetwo[3], person] 
            sheet.insert_row(row, index)
            index += 1
```

for some reason, valuetwo[3] is never inserted into the sheet, I just get 4 columns of data. No matter what data I test with (have tried using simple strings), this is always the case, the 4th value is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: example input:
['sample', 'input', 'data', 'stack', 'overflow']

expected output: each item in list gets its own cell in a row. Real output: ['sample', 'input', 'data', 'overflow']